# mysql group by clause with joins

Tags: mysql

i have two table in database

[image: tabels]

and I fired this query

```
SELECT  orderdate,priceeach 
FROM  orders AS T1 
INNER JOIN orderdetails AS T2 
ON T1.orderNumber = T2.orderNumber 
GROUP BY orderdate;
```

getting this error

```
ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains non aggregated column 'classicmodels.T2.priceEach' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

please help me with this and please also explain which statement or clause executes first in order and why i am getting this error.

because i tried same query with two different databases (dummy ones) and it worked.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in the result? do you want to find minimum or maximum of priceeach per order date?

Comment: basically what group by does is group identical rows and short them right? why its not working with single column?

Comment: That is `order by`

Comment: okay then what group does?

Comment: Group by wants to return only one row for the column you specify of orderdate. Problem is it doesn't know which row to take from the group because you need an aggregate of something, so the query knows which row to select. Also for every thing in the GroupBy has to be used in the select

Comment: @Nishant What exactly is your goal? please specify sample data and expected output in the question

Comment: @Edward can you please tell why it worked here http://imgur.com/a/jDRta i am really getting confuse how this whole query working one by one

Comment: Not sure you are getting what you think you are. As you have no order by, the group by price is then taking the first row from the rowset of table one for each differing price as well as matching the id from the ON clause and taking the first of those, in this case your table 2 happens to look ordered but that may not always be the case.

Comment: Thank you both... i got my answer after executing each statement independently one by one and matching  result of final query...